# How can I merge two dataframes with 'wildcards'?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple dataframe like so:

```
   p     b
0  a   buy
1  b   buy
2  a  sell
3  b  sell
```

and a lookup table like this:

```
   p     b    v
0  a   buy  123
1  a  sell  456
2  a     *  888
4  b     *  789
```

How can I merge (join) the two dataframes, but respecting the 'wildcard' in column b, i.e. the expected result is:

```
   p     b    v
0  a   buy  123
1  b   buy  789
2  a  sell  456
3  b  sell  789
```

The best I can come up with is this, but it's pretty ugly and verbose:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([
        ['a', 'buy'],
        ['b', 'buy'],         
        ['a', 'sell'],
        ['b', 'sell'],              
    ], columns = ['p', 'b'])
lookup = pd.DataFrame([
        ['a', 'buy', 123],
        ['a', 'sell', 456],
        ['a', '*', 888],
        ['b', '*', 789],        
], columns = ['p','b', 'v'])

x = data.reset_index()
y1 = pd.merge(x, lookup, on=['p', 'b'], how='left').set_index('index')
y2 = pd.merge(x[y1['v'].isnull()], lookup, on=['p'], how='left' ).set_index('index')
data['v'] = y1['v'].fillna(y2['v'])
```

Is there a smarter way?

Comment: In the expected result above, why aren't there any rows with `v` equal to 888?

Comment: Good question - it's because the wildcard only applies when there's no more specific match.

Comment: @Matthew if this is something you created, you need to think about the data model.

Comment: This problem is caused by porting the following SQL to pandas ```update  ... from L inner join R on L.p = R.p where (L.b = R.b or R.b = '*')``` - seems one of the few cases where SQL is much simpler than pandas!

Comment: @Matthew  Well thats means the SQL data model needs to looked at SQL is not better pandas... the problem is the root data model. This is a simple accounting problem- You need a rolling net per row in the data.

Comment: I'm not going to suggest the data model I inherited is perfect, but the idea of matching with wildcards is a fairly standard one so I feel the question stands. If you have a solution that works with a better data model then I could probably transform my data - I'm all ears!

Answer (score 6):

I think a little cleaner is to clean up the `wildcards` first:

```
In [11]: wildcards = lookup[lookup["b"] == "*"]

In [12]: wildcards.pop("b")  # ditch the * column, it'll confuse the later merge
```

Now you can combine the two merges (without needing `set_index`) with an [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
In [13]: res = df.merge(lookup, how="left")

In [14]: res
Out[14]:
   p     b      v
0  a   buy  123.0
1  b   buy    NaN
2  a  sell  456.0
3  b  sell    NaN

In [15]: res.update(df.merge(wildcards, how="left"), overwrite=False)

In [16]: res
Out[16]:
   p     b      v
0  a   buy  123.0
1  b   buy  789.0
2  a  sell  456.0
3  b  sell  789.0
```

Comment: I like this solution! The only hiccup is I have a case where there are multiple columns with (potential) wildcards. Its not obvious how I could extend this to work for that scenario.

Comment: @Matthew, unfortunely,  'b   buy  888.0' should be   'b   buy  789', but 3 upvotes, :-)

Comment: @Matthew let me just fix that!

Comment: the second merge needed to be how=left too (to stabilize the index). Will think about multiple wildcards (do you mean they could be in *any* column?).

Comment: @Matthew with multiple columns you're also going to get ambiguity or at least need to impose a precedence i.e. is two *s weaker than one *, should a * in column A be tried first before a * in column B. So I don't think it can come for free.

Answer (score 2):

I've found another solution, inspired by some of the ideas above (thanks all!). It's neater than my first attempt so I'll put it here, though I'm sure there's room for improvement. This solution assumes lookup is sorted so that wildcards are at the bottom of the table:

```
x = data.reset_index().merge(lookup, on=['p'], suffixes=["", "_y"])
x = x[(x['b'] == x['b_y']) | (x['b_y'] == '*')]
x = x.groupby('index').first() # see note about sorting lookup!
x[['p', 'b', 'c', 'v']]

         p     b    v
index                
0     0  a   buy  123
1     6  b   buy  789
2     4  a  sell  456
3     7  b  sell  789
```

Answer (score 1):

I find this intuitive:

```
def find_lookup(lookup, p, b):
    ps = lookup.p == p
    bs = lookup.b.isin([b, '*'])
    return lookup.loc[ps & bs].iloc[0].replace('*', b)

data.apply(lambda x: find_lookup(lookup, x.loc['p'], x.loc['b']), axis=1)

   p     b    v
0  a   buy  123
1  b   buy  789
2  a  sell  456
3  b  sell  789
```

Comment: Hmm I like where you're going. I think groupby -> apply might be cleaner though - let me think about it...